# Is a $C^1$ manifold closed?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

This question is rather a question of convention. Consider the subset of $R^2$ 
$$A=\cup_{n=2}^{\infty}B((1/n,0),1/n^2)).$$
Around each of its point, $A$ is locally diffeomorphic to $R^2$, or to a half space of $R^2$. But $A$ is not closed, because $0\notin A$. Is $A$ considered to be a $C^1$ manifold (with boundary)? Is it a submanifold of $R^2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it is. In fact it's an embedded $C^\infty$ submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

A simpler situation to think about: $(0,1)$ is a manifold, even though it's not closed in $\mathbb{R}$. It's also a "manifold with boundary" (the boundary is just empty).